# SSL Handshake ending with javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

We are trying to have client-server auth. The client and the server have 2 machines certificates signed by the same CA and Intermidiate CA. When tryng to initiate the handshake with javax.net.debug=ssl:handshake these are the logs after printing out the varoius certificates. The used protocol is TLS v.1.2 and the java is an OpenJDK 11

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.905 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:672|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, dss_sign, ecdsa_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [VARIOUS CAs]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.905 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.906 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|X509Authentication.java:213|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.907 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.908 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:775|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.908 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.908 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:290|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.908 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:321|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.913 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:396|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 11 88 67 1F E4 73 35   2B 1A 81 23 BF D7 40 57  ...g..s5+..#..@W
    .....AND MORE                                                k
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.921 CEST|ChangeCipherSpec.java:115|Produced ChangeCipherSpec message
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|37|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-9|2021-08-17 10:20:31.925 CEST|TransportContext.java:318|Fatal (HANDSHAKE_FAILURE): Couldn't kickstart handshaking (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: readHandshakeRecord
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1320)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
        at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
```

Update: it seems that in the JKS the certificate wit the correct algorithm cannot be found, used a piece of code to check if it can be found manually and it is working fine.
Is there any other way to check the certificates availble that are not matching?

Update 2:
Full debug masked

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.830 CEST|ClientHello.java:653|Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "31 18 43 1E A8 0B 29 B4 5A F0 F2 A3 C1 2D 0A 35 AA A4 93 79 5A 5E 38 88 48 ED 1E AF 76 A0 4A E6",
  "session id"          : "10 17 F6 A9 A3 E9 E1 4E 80 5E A0 95 7C 7B 53 03 17 59 84 98 55 71 A9 4F 13 68 C2 24 3A E6 CD 09",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x1301), TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x1302), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02C), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02B), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC030), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC02E), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0xC032), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02D), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC031), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC024), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC028), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC026), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384(0xC02A), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00A), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC014), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC005), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0xC00F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC023), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC027), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC025), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0xC029), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC009), TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC013), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC004), TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0xC00E), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=clienthostname.dmz.test-group.net
    },
    "status_request (5)": {
      "certificate status type": ocsp
      "OCSP status request": {
        "responder_id": <empty>
        "request extensions": {
          <empty>
        }
      }
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [x25519, secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, x448, ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "ec_point_formats (11)": {
      "formats": [uncompressed]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "status_request_v2 (17)": {
      "cert status request": {
        "certificate status type": ocsp_multi
        "OCSP status request": {
          "responder_id": <empty>
          "request extensions": {
            <empty>
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.3, TLSv1.2]
    },
    "psk_key_exchange_modes (45)": {
      "ke_modes": [psk_dhe_ke]
    },
    "key_share (51)": {
      "client_shares": [
        {
          "named group": x25519
          "key_exchange": {
            0000: 79 10 30 AA 4A 56 70 8B   51 26 11 78 9
              ..AND MORE
          }
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.830 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS13 handshake, length = 409
12:42:58.868 CEST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 3968

javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.873 CEST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:247|READ: TLSv1.2 handshake, length = 3968
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.874 CEST|ServerHello.java:872|Consuming ServerHello handshake message (
"ServerHello": {
  "server version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "61 1C E4 32 61 9B 53 5D B7 CF 38 FC DC 1A 01 86 42 67 0B 44 64 05 CF CB 88 01 A1 D7 45 6A 30 50",
  "session id"          : "61 1C E4 32 64 3A 16 64 2B 53 63 A5 68 C6 6B 1A 25 8F 9B 11 04 5D 42 A4 3B 0E 12 6E 57 57 15 C6",
  "cipher suite"        : "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0xC02F)",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "renegotiation_info (65,281)": {
      "renegotiated connection": [<no renegotiated connection>]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|ServerHello.java:968|Negotiated protocol version: TLSv1.2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:173|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:192|Consumed extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:163|Ignore unsupported extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.875 CEST|SSLSessionImpl.java:210|Session initialized:  Session(1629283378875|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: server_name
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: max_fragment_length
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: ec_point_formats
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: application_layer_protocol_negotiation
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: status_request_v2
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: extended_master_secret
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: supported_versions
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: key_share
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:215|Ignore impact of unsupported extension: renegotiation_info
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.876 CEST|SSLExtensions.java:207|Ignore unavailable extension: pre_shared_key
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.878 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:366|Consuming server Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": [
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "12 2F 77 E8 55 D7 E6 2A 5C 5A BC 82 98 CD 5F 94",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group",
    "not before"         : "2019-02-06 11:52:50.000 CET",
    "not  after"         : "2022-02-06 11:52:50.000 CET",
    "subject"            : "CN=prestest.sis.dom, OU=b2c, O=TEST Group AG, L=Dallas, ST=Dallas, C=COM",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: A8 E2 82 6A BA CD 96 8E   7C 
          ..AND MORE
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:false
          PathLen: undefined
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.37 Criticality=false
        ExtendedKeyUsages [
          serverAuth
          clientAuth
          timeStamping
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.18 Criticality=false
        IssuerAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=false
        KeyUsage [
          DigitalSignature
          Key_Encipherment
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: prestest.sis.dom
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: 1F B0 29 8F 09 13 12 A2   
  ..AND MORE    
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "17 13 7A 67 BC 5C EB ED 59 E9 F8 CF A0 D9 90 59",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group",
    "not before"         : "2017-10-20 15:23:27.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2027-10-19 15:23:27.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: D0 69 0E 0C 2A B6 1F 4C   D4 B1 B4 7C 59 3A
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.18 Criticality=false
        IssuerAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: A8 E2 82 6A BA CD 96 8E   7C CE 36 F9 2E A9 DC
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]},
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "13 B8 D6 3B 49 E6 08 EA 59 E9 E8 3E 59 5E 06 E3",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group",
    "not before"         : "2017-10-20 14:12:46.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2027-10-20 14:12:46.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: D0 69 0E 0C 2A B6 1F 4C   D4 B1 B4 7C 59 3A 
          ..AND MORE
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
]
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.879 CEST|X509TrustManagerImpl.java:238|Found trusted certificate (
  "certificate" : {
    "version"            : "v3",
    "serial number"      : "17 13 7A 67 BC 5C EB ED 59 E9 F8 CF A0 D9 90 59",
    "signature algorithm": "SHA256withRSA",
    "issuer"             : "CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group",
    "not before"         : "2017-10-20 15:23:27.000 CEST",
    "not  after"         : "2027-10-19 15:23:27.000 CEST",
    "subject"            : "CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group",
    "subject public key" : "RSA",
    "extensions"         : [
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
        AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: D0 69
          ..AND MORE
        ]
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=true
        BasicConstraints:[
          CA:true
          PathLen:2147483647
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.18 Criticality=false
        IssuerAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.15 Criticality=true
        KeyUsage [
          Key_CertSign
          Crl_Sign
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.17 Criticality=false
        SubjectAlternativeName [
          CN=TEST Corporate System CA, O=TEST Group
          RFC822Name: certificates.test@test-group.com
        ]
      },
      {
        ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
        SubjectKeyIdentifier [
        KeyIdentifier [
        0000: A8 E2 8
        ]
        ]
      }
    ]}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|ECDHServerKeyExchange.java:505|Consuming ECDH ServerKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ServerKeyExchange": {
  "parameters": {
    "named group": "secp256r1"
    "ecdh public": {
      0000: 04 25 
  ..AND MORE
    },
  },
  "digital signature":  {
    "signature algorithm": "rsa_pkcs1_sha256"
    "signature": {
      0000: 13 FA 5
   ..AND MORE
    },
  }
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:672|Consuming CertificateRequest handshake message (
"CertificateRequest": {
  "certificate types": [rsa_sign, dss_sign, ecdsa_sign]
  "supported signature algorithms": [ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, dsa_sha256, ecdsa_sha224, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, ecdsa_sha1, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
  "certificate authorities": [CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group, CN=TEST System CA, OU=Corporate Function IT, O=TEST Group AG, C=COM, CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, OU=Corporate Function IT, O=TEST Group AG, C=COM, CN=Test Service ID CA 1024 Class 1, C=COM, OU=Class 1 (Service Certificates), OU=CA Services, O=Test Services AG]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.881 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha512
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp384r1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha384
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_secp256r1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha256
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.882 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha224
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for EC
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: ecdsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for RSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: rsa_pkcs1_sha1
javax.net.ssl|ALL|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|X509Authentication.java:244|No X.509 cert selected for DSA
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:765|Unavailable authentication scheme: dsa_sha1
javax.net.ssl|WARNING|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateRequest.java:775|No available authentication scheme
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|ServerHelloDone.java:151|Consuming ServerHelloDone handshake message (
<empty>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:299|No X.509 certificate for client authentication, use empty Certificate message instead
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.883 CEST|CertificateMessage.java:330|Produced client Certificate handshake message (
"Certificates": <empty list>
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.884 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS12 handshake, length = 7
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.884 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 00 07 0B 00 00   03 00 00 00              ............
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.885 CEST|ECDHClientKeyExchange.java:400|Produced ECDHE ClientKeyExchange handshake message (
"ECDH ClientKeyExchange": {
  "ecdh public": {
    0000: 04 88 CE
  ..AND MORE                                                 .
  },
}
)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|24|http-nio-127.0.0.1-8080-exec-2|2021-08-18 12:42:58.885 CEST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS12 handshake, length = 70
```

Update 3: it seems to me that the keystore is not being loaded, from custom code it gets corrected loaded.

Comment: *We are trying to have client-server auth*  Post the details of your client certificate, and include the CAs sent by the server in the output.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have updated the question. I have tried  getting the alias from custom code passing the type RSA and it gets the correct one: 
`KeyManagerFactory kmf =KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

kmf.init(ks, "changeit".toCharArray());

KeyManager[] managers = kmf.getKeyManagers();

var manager509=(X509KeyManager)managers[0];

var alias=manager509.chooseServerAlias("RSA", null, null);`

Comment: Is your client cert signed directly by one of the CAs in the server's trust store that it sends as acceptable CAs in `"certificate authorities": [CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, O=TEST Group, CN=TEST System CA, OU=Corporate Function IT, O=TEST Group AG, C=COM, CN=TEST Corporate Root CA, OU=Corporate Function IT, O=TEST Group AG, C=COM, CN=Test Service ID CA 1024 Class 1, C=COM, OU=Class 1 (Service Certificates), OU=CA Services, O=Test Services AG]`?  If there are any intermediate certs missing, your client JVM won't be able to connect your client cert to any of the acceptable CAs.

Comment: @AndrewHenle yeah, the CAs are all in the trust store. One thing I noticed is that in the ClientHello is requested the hostname:   "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=clienthostname.dmz.test-group.net
    },
while the first certificate received is :
  SubjectAlternativeName [
          DNSName: prestest.sis.dom
        ]

Could this be the issue?

Comment: From what you've posted, it doesn't look like you're getting to the point of failing hostname validation yet. But maybe I missed something?  If you can, go ahead and fix that - you'll have to fix it anyway.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I checked that this was not the issue. I connected the remote debugger and checked all the flow. I manged to fix the issue at the end, the solution is in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the Axis client calling the Server.
Axis was loading the configuration from the **client-config.wsdd** from a product library **am-client.jar** that was setting as default the following property:

```
        <parameter name="axis.socketSecureFactory" value="com.rsa.webservice.transport.IMSSecureSocketFactory" />
```

The **IMSSecureSocketFactory** is NOT reading the property from the system for the keystore (javax.net.ssl.keyStore).
So the X509Authentication was reading from a KeyManager with no entry resulting in no certificate matching.

Adding the following propetiy to the AxisProperties solved the issue:

```
AxisProperties.setProperty("axis.socketSecureFactory","org.apache.axis.components.net.JSSESocketFactory");
```

I hope this can help someone else, it was really challenging to debug.